# Dynamically inserting a CSS class to navbar based on route

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Vue 2 and Vue-Router 2.

I'm trying to change the color of my app's navbar based on which route is visited. Here's what I have:

main.js:

```
import App from "../components/App.vue"    

const app = new Vue({
  router: Router,
  template: '<app></app>',
  components: { App }
}).$mount('#app')
```

App.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="navbar" v-on:class="{ colorNav: 'color-nav' }"></div>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        colorNav: false
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

With this setting, since `colorNav` property is false, the `color-nav` class is not added to the navbar. Working as intended.

Now the user goes to `/somepage`, which maps to SomePage.vue, which renders inside `router-view`. I would like SomePage.vue to change the `colorNav` property on App.vue so that `color-nav` class is added to the navbar.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can do it. I myself have different kind of headers depending of the page I am on.

One simple way can be to have some check on which route you are and depending on route change this variable. You can put a watch on `$route`, and whenever it changes, you can decide the value of `colorNav` depending on current route. Code will be something like:

```
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        colorNav: false
      }
    }
  watch: {
    '$route' () {
      if (this.$route.path === '/somepage') {
        this. colorNav = true
      }
      else {
        this. colorNav = false
      }  
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Another way to do it can be have this variable in some [centralised state](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch) or [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/) store and change this from each component's mounted block depending on requirement.

Answer (score 18):

These answers helped me, but I ended up using a different solution. Your template also has access to `$route` so you can do something like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="navbar" v-bind:class="{ 'color-nav': $route.path == '/somepage' }"></div>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>
```

The 'color-nav' class will be added if the `$route.path` is `/somepage`. I suppose this amounts to the same thing, but without having to add data properties or watchers. Once you have multiple possible classes, it could get messy though.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed now. Also, for anyone else...the shorter syntax is just `:class="..."`

Comment: Thank you a lot! After 2.5 hours searching for a way to get the route name inside a component, your solution fixed my issue!

Answer (score 6):

You can use in-component guards like:

1. beforeRouteEnter (Does not have access to `this` of the vue instance)
2. beforeRouteUpdate (Available v2.2 onwards)
3. beforeRouteLeave

---

```
const Foo = {
  template: `...`,
  beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {

  },
  beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {

  },
  beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {

  }
}
```

In each of the methods you have access to `to` and `from` variables which are the route objects containing the path.

So for your case you can use beforeRouteLeave, to know the `to.path` and accordingly modify your data property like so:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      colorNav: false
    }
  },
  beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
    if(to.path === '<your-route-name>') {
       this.colorNav = 'your-choice'
    }
    next() // Don't forget this
  }
}
```

If you forget call to `next()` your router won't proceed onto the route switching.

Comment: I like @saurabh's answer better, but yours was also very helpful (and I confirmed that it works). Thank you for taking the time to write it out! :)

Comment: @EgeErsoz Sure, no problem. I just added in case it helps you or someone else searching this question :)

Comment: @Amresh Venugopal, Seems you master vue.js. I need you help. Look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42454027/how-to-add-a-loading-icon-while-searching-vue-js-2