# Alter background color of NavBar inserted in App.vue from within sibling router-view component

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to change the background and text color of my navbar component depending on what page I am on in order to remove contrasting colors with the current pages background. Effectively wanting a light and dark theme variant for the TopNav component that is triggered by what page we are currently on.

My nav bar and page template is as below:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <TopNav />          ------> This is the navbar component whos css i want to alter
    <v-content>   
      <router-view></router-view>    -----> Depending on what the current page injected is.
    </v-content>
    <Footer />
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Using `<style>` tags without the `scoped` attribute work on changing the navbar background but unfortunately it does not revert back after navigating to another page.

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]? Use codesandbox.io, a node based multi-file environment editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing state of a component from a sibling level or child level component is really an anti-pattern.

Your best bet is going to be using a well established pattern to get the functionality you're after.

One way to do this is to bring in Vuex, and place your light/dark mode in the Vuex store (shared application level state management)
Then, you could setup your TopNav component to bind to a value in Vuex state (`this.$store.state.darkMode` for example)
Then, from anywhere in the application, you could commit a mutation to specify light mode, dark mode, toggle, etc...

Or, if you want it to always be route-specific (kinda sounds like this is the case) then you can setup your route definition something like this:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/light-component',
    name: 'LightComponent',
    component: () => LightComponent,
    meta: {
      darkMode: false,
    },
  },
  {
    path: '/dark-component',
    name: 'DarkComponent',
    component: () => DarkComponent,
    meta: {
      darkMode: true,
    },
  },
];
```

Then, in any component (your TopNav component for example) you could do something like:

```
<template>
  <div :class="darkModeClass">

...

// inside <script> ...

computed: {
  darkModeClass() {
    return { dark: !!this.$route.meta?.darkMode };
  }
}

...

<style scoped>
  .dark {
    /* css styles for dark mode */
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Your answer is spot on. I ended up doing something very similar from this answer I found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42336188/dynamically-inserting-a-css-class-to-navbar-based-on-route except I also incorporated in the use of a 'colorNav' boolean property in the routes meta field that I check on route changes.